# Can't access dialog.messageChild(messageToDialog) inside the dialoge box

Tags: outlook, dialog, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing a Microsoft Outlook add-in, and I'm facing two issues:

**Dialog Box Not Closing After Sign-In:**
My add-in loads inside the task pane, which opens a dialog box for signing in to a Microsoft account.
After successfully signing in, the dialog box doesn't close as expected.

**Data Communication Issue:**

I'm sending data from the parent task pane to the dialog box using the provided methods, but the dialog box doesn't seem to receive the data correctly.

- Sample Code:

**Taskpane code where I open my dialoge box**

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(popupUrl, dialogOptions, (result) => {
  const dialog = result.value;
  const messageToDialog = JSON.stringify({
    isDialog: localStorage.getItem('isDialog'),
    companySsoId: companyDomainId,
  });

  dialog.messageChild(messageToDialog);
});
```

**Dialogue box code**

```
 Office.onReady((info) => {
    console.log('Data 3: ', info);
    if (info.isOfficeInitialized) {
      Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DialogParentMessageReceived, (arg) => {
        console.log('Data 4: ');
        try {
          const messageFromParent = JSON.parse(arg.getArgs().message);
          console.log('Received message from parent: ', messageFromParent);
          // Handle the message from the task pane as needed.
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing the message from parent:', error);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

The issue is my code doesn't enters **Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync** this block in the dialoge box code (Data 3 is logged in the console **BUT** Data 4 is not)

Comment: Nobody will provide you with the answers on two questions at once. You need to separate your 2 questions into 2 different threads. Now for your first question, there is not enough information about what you are doing; you need to provide the code. Please note [close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialog?view=common-js-preview#office-office-dialog-close-member(1)) function is asynchronous, see the [best parctices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-best-practices#open-another-dialog-immediately-after-closing-one) on it.

Comment: The second question is about asynchronous nature of the opening dialog. You need to wait a bit to send the message to the dialog, while it will be initialized. You may simply add the delay before sending the message to the child and see your dialog receive the message from parent. To make it more robust refer to this [solution](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2372#issuecomment-1214564587). Once again start from separating your questions and ppl will help you on each one.

Comment: Oh, yes, one more resource which will provide you with step-by-step instructions and sample applications to [Authenticate and authorize with the Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api). Please take a time and read through before asking again your questions. You'll most likely find the answer yourself.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Thank you so much for the second reply, it really helped me solved my problem regarding Data communication. I am already following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api this article but still faced these two issues somehow.